# {"errors":["Invalid image URL"]} with aviary integration

Tags: javascript, java, html, image, aviary

I am doing image editing integration with Aviary. 
Below is the html code

```
<body>
 <a href="#" onclick="return launchEditor('editableimage1','http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg');">
 <img id="editableimage1" src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg"/></a>
    <br>
    <form id="myform" action="" method="post">
<input id="hf" type="hidden" name="url">
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://feather.aviary.com/js/feather.js"></script>


<!-- Instantiate the widget -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
        apiKey: '1234567',
        apiVersion: 3,
         theme: 'light',
        tools: ['draw','text'],
        onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
            var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
            img.src = newURL;
            console.log('newURL '+newURL);
            document.getElementById("hf").value=newURL;
            featherEditor.close();
            //document.forms["myform"].submit();
        }
    });
    function launchEditor(id, src) {
        featherEditor.launch({
            image: id,
            url: src
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>                         
 </body>
```

On opening the above html:

1. Image will be rendered.
2. On click of the image, image editing tool will open with the image in it.

But if I replace the url with any other image url say `http://ipaddress:8080/ImageCheck/imgjsp.jsp` which actually renders image in the browser.

1. Image will be rendered.
2. On click of the image, image editing tool opens and close immediately with the error `{"errors":["Invalid image URL"]}` . Tool is unable to get image into its server for editing from my UrL.

What is the difference between "http://ipaddress:8080/ImageCheck/imgjsp.jsp" and  "http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg" for tool to behave differently. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We are getting the same error too, I've did some searching and found this:
https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202903359-Migrating-from-the-Aviary-SDK-to-the-Adobe-Creative-SDK-Beta

It looks like Aviary has updated their API

Answer (score 0):

is http://ipaddress:8080/ImageCheck/imgjsp.jsp points to local ip?
according to https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/web/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html, "requires that the image at the location be publicly available as our server must download it.".

On the other hand, we were able to pass base64 encoded image as a value for url parameter. This way, no need to have actual image to be stored first.
(This approach is not working for us when using hi-res version of Aviary image tool).